# When was the first quarter first used for moon phase?

Tags: astronomy

For this doesn't make sense - we see one *half* of moon, not one *quarter* (at least compared to full moon).

Comment: Quarter moon refers to quarter of the way through the cycle, not the part we see,  [Quarter moon or a half moon?](https://earthsky.org/moon-phases/is-it-a-quarter-or-a-half-moon)

Comment: I see. But why is with first quarter used fraction of the orbit and not fraction of visible moon?

Comment: This is indeed inconsistent, and even [Astronomy Glossary](https://www.the-observatory.org/astronomy-glossary) states that "First quarter is often referred to as half moon". I am not sure how this name mismatch originated, but it is not unusual with long-used traditional names. I wonder if quarters go all the way back to Ptolemy.

Comment: This is indeed inconsistent, and even [Astronomy Glossary](https://www.the-observatory.org/astronomy-glossary) states that "First quarter is often referred to as half moon". Aristarchus in his [On the sizes and distances of the sun and moon (c. 250 BC)](https://archive.org/details/aristarchusofsam00heatuoft/page/352) refers to (in Heath's translation) "*when the Moon appears to us halved*". I am not sure how this name mismatch originated, but it is not unusual with long-used traditional names. I wonder if "quarter Moons" go back to Ptolemy's Almagest.

Comment: Well, it is true that us Terran observers only see one-quarter of the moon's surface lit up. :-) .  The fact that half the surface is the most ever lit (plus/minus epsilon) leads us to wonder whether we should call the full moon a "half moon"